# G1 garbage collector tuning

Tags: performance, java-7, garbage, g1gc

I have an application running on Java 7 update 45 on Hotspot JVM. I am trying to tweak the parameters to work for a low latency application and below are the JVM parameters i set for this run. The timings in the individual steps in GC log (approx 25ms) does not add up to the pause time (>600ms). 
How do i know what is causing this pause time to be so high? In most of the collections they add up fine and are with in the pause time goal. I see such large pauses occasionally, one in 15-20 mins or so (not so regular though).

-server -Xmx2g -Xms2g -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=30 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=9 -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4M -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45 -XX:+PrintTLAB -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xloggc:/integral/logs/gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps  -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3026 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

```
2014-01-28T16:16:12.084+0000: 27507.054: Application time: 8.9506630 seconds
2014-01-28T16:16:12.084+0000: 27507.055: [GC pause (young)
Desired survivor size 81788928 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:    2299088 bytes,    2299088 total
- age   2:    1732832 bytes,    4031920 total
- age   3:    1748064 bytes,    5779984 total
- age   4:    1709368 bytes,    7489352 total
- age   5:    1732360 bytes,    9221712 total
- age   6:    1722776 bytes,   10944488 total
- age   7:    1712168 bytes,   12656656 total
- age   8:    1706240 bytes,   14362896 total
- age   9:    1692040 bytes,   16054936 total
- age  10:    1736008 bytes,   17790944 total
- age  11:    1566384 bytes,   19357328 total
- age  12:    1508456 bytes,   20865784 total
- age  13:    1491480 bytes,   22357264 total
- age  14:    1652136 bytes,   24009400 total
- age  15:    1502120 bytes,   25511520 total
 27507.055: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 12464, predicted base time: 7.97 ms, remaining time: 22.03 ms, target pause time: 30.00 ms]
 27507.055: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 298 regions, survivors: 9 regions, predicted young region time: 12.39 ms]
 27507.055: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 298 regions, survivors: 9 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 20.36 ms, target pause time: 30.00 ms]
, 0.0236600 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 22.0 ms, GC Workers: 9]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 27507055.7, Avg: 27507057.0, Max: 27507058.7, Diff: 3.1]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 2.1, Avg: 3.8, Max: 5.2, Diff: 3.1, Sum: 34.4]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 1.9, Avg: 2.3, Max: 3.0, Diff: 1.1, Sum: 20.8]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 4, Avg: 11.7, Max: 23, Diff: 19, Sum: 105]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 1.2]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 12.9, Avg: 13.1, Max: 13.3, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 117.6]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.5, Max: 0.8, Diff: 0.8, Sum: 4.8]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 17.7, Avg: 19.9, Max: 21.5, Diff: 3.8, Sum: 178.8]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 27507076.4, Avg: 27507076.9, Max: 27507077.2, Diff: 0.8]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.3 ms]
   [Other: 1.3 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.3 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.6 ms]
   [Eden: 1192.0M(1192.0M)->0.0B(1192.0M) Survivors: 36.0M->36.0M Heap: 1796.8M(2048.0M)->605.0M(2048.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.00, real=0.64 secs] 
2014-01-28T16:16:12.719+0000: 27507.690: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.6354760 seconds
```

Comment: By looking at the worker end times, this time is spent after the parallel stage is complete. I am  guess this is initial Initial mark phase that is piggybacked on to STW young collection. How do i trace it and tune it?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but, tens of milliseconds will be futile for G1, hundreds of them might work. Also you are giving the size of the heap region yourself, which means that the shrink and grow of the regions, which directly influence the time you specified will not be honoured.